# The instance member 'name' can't be accessed in an initializer

Tags: dart

I get the error, when declaring a `_disposers` variable.

> The instance member 'name' can't be accessed in an initializer.

```
class FormStore = _FormStore with _$FormStore;

abstract class _FormStore with Store {

  @observable
  String name = '';

  List<ReactionDisposer> _disposers = [
    reaction((_) => name, validateUsername), // error on name and on validateUsername
  ];

  // ...
```

It prompts

> Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different
> expression

Why there is the error and why this error disapears if put `late` before `List<ReactionDisposer> _disposers`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't initialize an instance member like `_disposers` using other instance members (like `name`) because dart doesn't let you use a reference to "this" in initializers.

https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#implicit_this_reference_in_initializer

When you use `late` it becomes lazy, which means it will get initialized/evaluated only when needed (usually when you call it).